# Getting the Data as a CSV file directly instead of a List of object from spring-data-jpa

Tags: oracle, csv, jpa, java-8, spring-data-jpa

Is it possible to get the data from spring-data JPA in the form of CSV data instaed of `ArrayList` of pojos like

Below is the interface extending `JpaRepository`.

```
public interface FactAggRepository extends JpaRepository<FactAggRepository,Integer> {

@Query("select p from FactAggRepository as p where p.pId=:pId and p.periodStart=:periodStart")
public List<FactAggRepository> getAggregates(@Param("pId") Long pId,@Param("periodStart")LocalDateTime periodStart);

@Query("select p from UsageAgg as p where p.pId=:pId")
public List<UsageAgg> UsageAggregates(@Param("pId") Long pId);

}
```

Autowiring the repository to use the same methods as follows.

```
fetchedRecord = AggRepo.getAggregates(pId, periodStart);
```

Now the above the code returnd the List. Is it possible to get the CSV file with the data in the List without any conversion.please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[Spring Data](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data) is here to handle communication with data sources layers. Unfortunately, CSV is not a data store handled natively.

You have to use a third-party dependency such as [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) to transform those POJOs to CSV.